# Emulator opens all activities when clicking just the above...?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, manifest

here I am again.

I have a problem with my menu in combination with my activities.

When I run my emulator, and click the uppest item in the list, the emulator opens all list activities.

Hopefully someone can help me.. Thank you all in advance!

My Menu.Java:

```
package com.jacob.eindproject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener { 


String classes[] = { "BMI- Calculator", "Ondergewicht", "Gezond Gewicht", "Overgewicht"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
//Positie 0 is het eerste item (dus de BMI-Calculator.)
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

switch(position)
{
case 0: 
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);   

case 1: 
Intent openOndergewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ondergewicht.class);
startActivity(openOndergewicht);    

case 2: 
Intent openGezondgewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Gezond_gewicht.class);
startActivity(openGezondgewicht);   

case 3: 
Intent openOvergewicht = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Overgewicht.class);
startActivity(openOvergewicht); 

break;
}


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jacob.eindproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Inleiding"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category  android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>        

    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Ondergewicht"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.activity.ONDERGEWICHT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>        

    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Gezond_gewicht"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action      android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.activity.GEZOND_GEWICHT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>   

    <activity
        android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.Overgewicht"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                        <action   android:name="com.jacob.eindproject.activity.OVERGEWICHT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>                         

</application>
```

First, there opens the Inleiding, it's my logo, and after 5 seconds it disappears.

After that, I want the menu with 4 items, 1 for the MainActivity.java, wich is a BMI-calculator. The last 3 items are informational items, about weight and stuff.

Somebody who knows the answer?

Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason all your activities open is because you don't have `break` statements at the end of each `case` clause in your `switch`. You need to add a `break` at the end of each `case` block.

Also, you should remove the `<intent-filter>` tags from all of your activities except the first one  (`Inleiding`) that contains `CATEGORY=DEFAULT` and `ACTION=MAIN`. You don't need those and they will just confuse you.